# Exchange 2007/Outlook 2007 E-mail "Chucking"

Tags: exchange-2007, outlook

Quick  question,

Outlook users in our environment often will get "chucks" of emails, groupings all at once, every 10 minutes or so instead of real time, or a minute or two delay. Exchange and Outlook should be notifying each other of changes every 30 seconds or so from what I know.

Some FYIs: We connect to our Exchange Server over a couple of tunneled linked T1s, on a different colo'd subnet. this is the only issue we are experiencing at this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Real-time message delivery depends on the exchange server being able to notify the Outlook clients when a new message arrives so that the client can then go and pull the message down from the server. In the past, I've seen this behavior when a firewall rule has prevented this notification from happening.

Comment: great. I'll look down that avenue.